# Failed to update database after upgrading to 8.9.13

Tags: database, updating

I'm new to drupal and was recently tasked with upgrading the drupal core version of one of our sites. I upgraded from 8.3 to 8.9.13 and everything went smooth enough until it came time to update the database. Here, I was told that two updates had failed.

> system module
> Update #8501
> Failed: Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Exception thrown while performing a schema update. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: ALTER TABLE {content_moderation_state_field_data} ADD UNIQUE KEY `content_moderation_state__lookup` (`content_entity_type_id`, `content_entity_id`, `content_entity_revision_id`, `workflow`, `langcode`); Array ( ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->wrapSchemaException() (line 1619 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
>
> content_moderation module
> Update #8700
> Failed: Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Exception thrown while performing a schema update. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: ALTER TABLE {content_moderation_state_field_data} ADD UNIQUE KEY `content_moderation_state__lookup` (`content_entity_type_id`, `content_entity_id`, `content_entity_revision_id`, `workflow`, `langcode`); Array ( ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->wrapSchemaException() (line 1619 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php)

The table in question is InnoDB and utf8mb4_general_ci.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: `v8.3 to 8.9.13 `

Dont bump to many versions. Perform incremental upgrades. You will probably resolve your issue. Try with one or 2 versions upgrade once. and continue the same.

Comment: [Drupal composer project changed](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/migrating-the-composer-project-for-drupal-earlier-than-880) with 8.8. 

Have you done the necessary steps? Otherwise you should do those, they may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Does rolling back to my previous version just involve returning all previous v8.3 core files and then reverting database using my sql backup?

Comment: Yes, you need to revert core files and restore database as well. before reverting drop all the tables in the current database as restoring wont drop tables which are not present in the backup. you can drop all tables using `drush sql-drop`  command.